# CosmosDB: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a mongodb update query that works when I run it in the shell but the same is throwing an error when I run the query in **Query shell** of  azure cosmos-db. Initially I used the following query.

```
db.sample.update(
              {
                _id: ObjectId("690655905jgj580")
              },
              {
                $set: {
                  user_data: {
                    eid: "E9076",name: "Jhon",email:"Jhon@xyz.com", posted_on: "1621509348056"
                  },
                }
              }
            )
```

The above mentioned query fails to update the record via Query Shell and gives an error.

After looking into other related questions I found that both the key and value must be in quotes so I modified the query as follows. But, still I'm getting the same error: **JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'**

```
db.sample.update(
                  {
                    "_id": ObjectId("690655905jgj580")
                  },
                  {
                    "$set": {
                      "user_data": {
                        "eid": "E9076","name": "Jhon","email":"Jhon@xyz.com", 
                       "posted_on": "1621509348056"
                  },
                }
              }
            )
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong here?

Comment: Seems to be a perfectly valid query (assuming you made up _id which isn't a valid length), so would seem to be a client problem. With "Query shell", do you mean the mongo shell in the Azure portal, and is your CosmosDB instance set up in mongodb mode?

Comment: Yes the data are just dummy values to serve the purpose. With Query shell I mean mongo shell in azure portal. Yes cosmode db instance setup in mongodb mode

Comment: Pasting `db.sample.update({ _id: ObjectId("60ed407d372d2f6876565018")}, { $set: { user_data: { eid: "E9076",name: "Jhon",email:"Jhon@xyz.com", posted_on: "1621509348056"},}})` into the portal (with a sample document inserted) gives me 
`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`, so don't see your error.

Comment: The query itself is working when I try it in the shell editor in the azure cosmosdb instance but the same is not working in the Query Shell! Is the query enough to work in the Query shell?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between "shell editor" and "query shell" in Azure portal is, but the query I pasted works if pasted into the "Mongo Shell" opened using "Open Mongo Shell" inside "Data Explorer". How exactly are you getting to the query shell that is not working?

Comment: @AnjaliA - Please edit your question to show details of your Cosmos DB account confirming this is indeed using MongoDB API vs Core (SQL) API, as well as showing where, in the portal, you are attempting to run this query. Asking you to do this since others have taken your exact query and had success running it within the Azure Portal's shell.

Comment: @AnjaliA - also, have you attempted to do a simpler operation (like a generic find with no parameters)? Do you receive the same error?

Comment: In the mongo shell all the queries are working. Sure I'll update the question